# tcbtheorem: Twoline title with the description starting below "Theorem #"

Tags: environments, tcolorbox

I'm using the `tcolorbox` to set a couple of theorems in my thesis. The problem is, that the longest "name" (What they call description in the Documentation.) is **just** too long for one line.

Here is a MWE (this is the somewhat customized style I would like to use):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{many}

\definecolor{theoremgray}{rgb}{0.93, 0.93, 0.93}
\newtcbtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%
{
    enhanced, 
    frame empty, breakable,
    colframe=black, coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries , colbacktitle=white,
    fontupper=\slshape, colback=theoremgray,
    borderline={0.5mm}{0mm}{theoremgray},
    attach boxed title to top left,,
    boxed title style={boxrule=0.5mm, rounded corners},
    boxed title size={copy},
    minipage boxed title
}{theo}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}{This is a slightly too long title that just causes a break}{test1}
Some text in my theorem.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What I would like to do is to set it up such, that only "Theorem 1:" is written in the first line of the title box and the name (description) in a second line, however, it should start directly under "Theorem 1:". That way, the whole thing would fit in one line.
I checked the documentation of the `tcolorbox` package and tried a couple of things, like using `separator sign={\newline}` (which does not do anything for me) or `description formatter=\newline` which starts the description in a new line, but with wrong alignment.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

With `tcolorbox` v4.50 (2021/05/21) or newer, this can be achieved with `theorem hanging indent=0pt`, a newly added key suggested in my feature requestion [`tcolorbox#126`](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/126).

The following example has been updated to be compatible with `tcolorbox` both older and not-older than v4.50.

**Original answer:**

This patches the internal macro `\tcb@theo@title` used to typeset the title of a tcb theorem, and deletes the hanging indent part.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{many}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\definecolor{theoremgray}{rgb}{0.93, 0.93, 0.93}

\newtcbtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%
{
    enhanced, 
    frame empty, breakable,
    colframe=black, coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries , colbacktitle=white,
    fontupper=\slshape, colback=theoremgray,
    borderline={0.5mm}{0mm}{theoremgray},
    attach boxed title to top left,,
    boxed title style={boxrule=0.5mm, rounded corners},
    boxed title size={copy},
    minipage boxed title,
    separator sign={},
    description formatter=\newline,
    % use pgfkeys handler `/.try` to keep backward compatibility 
    theorem hanging indent/.try=0pt,
}{theo}


\makeatletter
% for tcolorbox before v4.50 (2021/05/21), patch \tcb@theo@title
% usage: title={\tcb@theo@title{Theorem}{\thetcbcounter}{<description>}}
\IfPackageAtLeastTF{tcolorbox}{2021/05/21}{
}{
  \xpatchcmd\tcb@theo@title
    {\hangindent\wd\z@\hangafter=1}
    {}
    {}{\fail}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}{This is a slightly too long title that just causes a break}{test1}
  Some text in my theorem.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @muzimuzhi Z: Unfortunately the code patch shown in this solution doesn't work with updated packages xpatch (2020/03/25 v0.3a) and tclorborx (2021/06/14 version 4.51). I used this solution for quite a long time.

Comment: @JardaFait See the updated answer.