# \newtcbtheorem (tcolorbox) + enumerate environment (enumitem package): Use of \tcb@@icolorbox doesn't match its definition

Tags: tcolorbox, enumitem

I like the powerful library [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox). But I found myself in trouble trying to combine the `\newtcbtheorem` described in chapter 17 with the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package. My simplest theorem definition looks like:

```
\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}
  \newtcbtheorem[auto counter,number within=chapter]{mathexam}{Příklad}{%
    enforce breakable,         % breakable,
    compress page,
    enhanced,
  }{mai}
```

Then I would like to use it like this:

```
  \begin{mathexam}{Find the prmitive functions for:
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item \(f(x) = 2x+5\),
      \item \(f(x) = \sin x\),
      \item \(f(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\),
    \end{enumerate}
    }{mai:exam118}
    \blindmathtrue
    \blindmathpaper
  \end{mathexam}
```

I also try the patch

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566094/
% Twoline title with the description starting below “Theorem #”
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\tcb@theo@title
  {\hangindent\wd\z@\hangafter=1}
  {}
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother
```

But compiler is not satisfied:

```
! Use of \tcb@@icolorbox doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...

l.37     }{mai:exam118}
```

---

My full MNWE is:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
  \usepackage[math]{blindtext}
  \usepackage{xpatch}
  \usepackage{enumitem}

\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}
  \newtcbtheorem[auto counter,number within=chapter]{mathexam}{Příklad}{%
    enforce breakable,         % breakable,
    compress page,
    enhanced,
  }{mai}

    % https://texblog.org/2013/02/27/on-paragraphs-in-texlatex/
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566094/
    % Twoline title with the description starting below “Theorem #”
    \makeatletter
    \xpatchcmd\tcb@theo@title
      {\hangindent\wd\z@\hangafter=1}
      {}
      {}{\fail}
    \makeatother
  
\begin{document}
  \begin{mathexam}{Find the prmitive functions for:
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item \(f(x) = 2x+5\),
      \item \(f(x) = \sin x\),
      \item \(f(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\),
    \end{enumerate}
    }{mai:exam118}
    \blindmathtrue
    \blindmathpaper
  \end{mathexam}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it looks very wrong to misuse the title for such a long text. Why don't you put the text in the upper part?

Comment: I understand you want to write a problem and its solution. Instead of placing the problem into the title, I'd suggest to place it into `upper part` and the solution after the `\tcblower`. You can even use a `bicolor` box to better distinguish both parts.